# How can I find the arclength of this complicated function?

Tags: calculus, integration, riemann-integration, arc-length

I want to integrate $$\int_0^a \sqrt{1+\left(\frac{d\delta(x)}{dx}\right)^2} dx$$

Where $$ \delta(x) = C_1 \sqrt{a^2-x^2} \left(C_2 \left(\frac{x}{a}\right)^3+C_3 \left(\frac{x}{a}\right)^2+C_4(\frac{x}{a})+C_5\right)$$

I think I may be able to do this with some form of coordinate transform, but I just don't see it at this moment. I also banged it into Wolfram Mathematica with no success. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is there a reason you expect this to have a closed form answer? Not even a simple parabola like $y=x^2$ has a closed form for arc length.

Comment: I guess perhaps there is not a reason to expect a closed form. How would you know whether to expect / not expect a closed form? Perhaps there exists a simplification that would allow a better approximation than nothing?

Comment: It's worth noting that there IS a closed form for a parabola. It's been done on this site.